# Implicitly resolve the correct class for an abstract argument

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Given the following code:

```cs
static class StaticClass
{
  public static void DoSomething(BaseClass Value)
  {
  }
}

abstract class BaseClass
{
}

class DerivedClassForString : BaseClass
{
  public string Value { get; }

  public DerivedClassForString(string Value)
  {
    this.Value = Value;
  }

  public static implicit operator DerivedClassForString(string Value)
  {
    return new DerivedClassForString(Value);
  }
}

class DerivedClassForInt32 : BaseClass
{
  public int Value { get; }

  public DerivedClassForInt32(int Value)
  {
    this.Value = Value;
  }

  public static implicit operator DerivedClassForInt32(int Value)
  {
    return new DerivedClassForInt32(Value);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```cs
StaticClass.DoSomething("Hello world!"); //This should create an instance of DerivedClassForString
StaticClass.DoSomething(16); //This should create an instance of DerivedClassForInt32
```

This however does not work.

Is there any way to give the compiler a hint to go through the derived classes and search for the implicit resolver?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-generics-introduction/amp/

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you made a mistake in your example, I assume both of those statements shouldn't return a DerivedClassFor**String**? However, if they should I'd say the solution should be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other way of doing it would be defining the implicit conversions within `BaseClass` itself :

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public static implicit operator BaseClass(string Value)
    {
        return new DerivedClassForString(Value);
    }

    public static implicit operator BaseClass(int Value)
    {
        return new DerivedClassForInt32(Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Simon Mattes here's how you do it

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what `StaticClass.DoSomething` and `BaseClass` really does, you could make both `BaseClass` and `StaticClass.DoSomething` generic :

```
static class StaticClass
{
    public static void DoSomething<T>(BaseClass<T> Value)
    {
    }
}

class BaseClass<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }

    public BaseClass(T Value)
    {
      this.Value = Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator BaseClass<T>(T Value)
    {
        return new BaseClass<T>(Value);
    }
}
```

If you want the compiler to infer `T` when calling `StaticClass.DoSomething` you'll need to make DoSomething look like this though :

```
static class StaticClass
{
    public static void DoSomething<T>(T Value)
    {
        BaseClass<T> realValue = Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea -- in my case however, I need to find a way for the compiler to somehow understand that when providing a string, an instance of DerivedClassForString should be created, while for other types, respective classes should be used. Hence, I need to link them somehow without creating overloads for every type I want to support, which would be Plan B.

Comment: @SimonMattes Then you have to define the implicit conversions in `BaseClass`, do you want me to post an other answer or is this one useless to you and I can just edit it?

Comment: I did have the same idea, unfortunately compiler error CS0556: (User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type) prevents you from doing so